# Execute code before codable decode type check is executed?

Tags: swift, codable, vapor

Is it possible to execute code after `decode` is called but before type check is carry out?

```swift
let o7 = try decoder.decode(Organization.self, from: o6)
o7.configure()
return o7.save(on: request.db).flatMap { page in
    return request.eventLoop.future("done")
}
```

It raise an error:

> caught: typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, App.Event>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [ModelCodingKey(stringValue: "events", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Could not decode property", underlyingError: Optional(Swift.DecodingError.keyNotFound(ModelCodingKey(stringValue: "events", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key ModelCodingKey(stringValue: "events", intValue: nil) ("events").", underlyingError: nil)))))

`o7` is not yet matching the type requirements, but `o7.configure()` does the needed steps, is it possible to "ask" check type after `configure` was called?

---

This is the JSON: `{"name": "xxx"}`
And here is the type:

```swift
final class Organization:  Content {
    var name: String?
    var events: [String: Event]
}
```

as you see I need to initialize `events` to avoid typeMismatch error. I do it in `configure` method.

Comment: Again it would be much easier to help if you show its migration, model and the JSON string

Comment: hi, I added JSON to the question :)

Comment: So events is optional. Btw show your Model migration

Comment: no no, event is not optional, this is the trick, but it is not sent in the JSON, so I have to add it inbetween `var events: [String: Event]`

Comment: So create another Model to decode it.

Comment: Am I right that both class should be `final`, and I can not inherit one from the other?

Comment: Not sure what's wrong declaring it as optional. What difference does it make?

Comment: In relatity Organization has 27 fields, and Vapor annotations, and extending Vapor's `Model`. I did not copy here all the uninportant details

Comment: But declaring it as optional shouldn't make any difference other than allowing you to decode your JSON without events

Answer (score 0):

try adding CodingKeys, this will exclude "var events" from the json decodable.

```
final class Organization: Codable {
    var name: String?
    var events: [String: Event] = [:]
    
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name
    }
}
```